# Excel data model: Return last non blank

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I am struggling with getting only the last non blank value for each ticket.
In the Power Pivot measure, I have used a function `LASTNONBLANK()` , but the outcome was not reliable - probably because data model does not consider the original order of rows.
Excel formula or VBA is not an option and I think that in `Power Query` it will not be very efficient.

| ticket | step | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7/28/2021 04:15 PM |  |
| 1 | 2 | 7/28/2021 04:23 PM | a |
| 1 | 3 | 7/28/2021 04:30 PM |  |
| 1 | 4 | 7/28/2021 04:37 PM | b |
| 1 | 5 | 7/28/2021 04:44 PM |  |
| 1 | 6 | 7/28/2021 04:51 PM |  |
| 1 | 7 | 7/28/2021 04:59 PM |  |
| 2 | 1 | 7/29/2021 01:51 PM | a |
| 2 | 2 | 7/29/2021 02:49 PM | b |
| 2 | 3 | 7/29/2021 03:47 PM | c |
| 2 | 4 | 7/29/2021 04:44 PM |  |
| 2 | 5 | 7/29/2021 05:42 PM | a |
| 2 | 6 | 7/29/2021 06:39 PM |  |

For ticket "1", the returned value should be "b" (step 4) and for ticket "2", the returned value should be "a" (step 5).

| ticket | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |

Comment: If an excel formula or vba is not an option, what are you left with?

Comment: Haqve you tried combining `LASTNONBLANK()` with `MAX()` within the "steps" column?

Comment: @SolarMike Power Pivot and Power Query.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty I did, but the result was not correct
`test:=CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(q_SU[value],MAX(q_SU[step])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PBI community helped me to create the Power Pivot measure with 2 different solutions, both working smoothly.

```
VAR _lasttimestampnonblank =
CALCULATE ( MAX ( Data[timestamp] ), Data[value] <> BLANK () )
RETURN
IF (
HASONEVALUE ( Data[ticket] ),
CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Data[value] ), Data[timestamp] = _lasttimestampnonblank )
)
```

and a second solution:

```
Measure 2 = 
    VAR __Table = FILTER('Table7',[value]<>"")
    VAR __Max = MAXX(__Table,[timestamp])
RETURN
    MAXX(FILTER(__Table,[timestamp] = __Max),[value])
```

Answer (score 2):

Especially since the data is sorted, it is pretty simple in Power Query:

- Remove the blank Value lines
- Group by ticket number

  - Return the last Value in each group

*(if it were not sorted, you would just add a sort to each subtable in the Group)*

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table28"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ticket", Int64.Type}, 
        {"step", Int64.Type}, 
        {"timestamp", type datetime}, 
        {"value", type text}}),

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([value] <> null)),
 
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"ticket"}, {
        {"Last Non-Blank", each List.Last([value])}
        })

in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Did not know about List.Last :)
Do I understand correctly, that there is probably no way how to get same result with a measure instead of creating a new query?

Comment: @MalyMajo I cannot answer that question. I do not know enough about Power Pivot and measures to be able to provide that information.  I provided a PQ solution since that was one of your tags.

Comment: ok, understood. I was hoping more for Power Pivot solution, because the real data source is quite huge and running another query would slow it down even more than it is now. :) I will wait few days and if nobody replies, I will mark you answer as the best one.